# Array Index out of bounds Exception on second test case

Tags: java, arrays, indexoutofboundsexception

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class Little_elephant
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int t = scan.nextInt();
        int arr[] = new int[100];
        int inversions, localInversions;
        for(int i = 0; i < t; i++)
        {
            inversions = 0;
            localInversions = 0;
            int n = scan.nextInt();
            for(int j = 0; j < n; j++)
            {
                arr[j] = scan.nextInt();
            }
            for(int j = 0; j < n - 1; j++)
            {
                for(int k = j + 1; j < n; k++)
                {
                    if(arr[j] > arr[k])
                    {
                        inversions++;
                    }
                }
                if(arr[j] > arr[j+1])
                    localInversions++;
            }
            if(inversions == localInversions)
                System.out.println("YES");
            else
                System.out.println("No");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The program is showing no error on compilation but is getting an array index out of bounds exception at 23rd line. Also the error is when I try more than one case i.e t>1. Please someone help me!

Comment: So what's the value of `n`? Ideally, show a [mcve]... this looks like it's more complicated than it needs to be to demonstrate the problem, and I suspect that while reducing it you'll find the answer.

Comment: Please include some input, as well as the expected output and/or describe the semantics of your program.

Comment: This question could be closed as off topic because it does not include an MCVE. Please include the values you use and you should also work on improving your variable names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a loop `for(int k = j + 1; j < n; k++)`
You're increasing `k` but the condition is on `j`

Answer (score 0):

Your nested for loop for k on line 21 is not stating a terminating clause for k, but rather for j. So right now your loop looks like this:

```
for(int k = j + 1; j < n; k++)
```

Where it should be saying:

```
for(int k = j + 1; k < n; k++)
```

Notice how k is less than n, not j less than n.